# lucene index match

Tags: lucene, match

I am trying to use Lucene for doing undup or dedup match. Essentially I have a file with records which I want to group based on certain fields (fuzzy search) and get back a result with a match key that tells me which records within that file matched to each other.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you using lucene (there are a lot of editions of it for various languages/frameworks)? Help us help you.

Comment: I am using Java Lucene 3.6. I can loop through the input file after indexing and search against the index on the fields I am interested in. This seems inefficient and hence I was wondering if there is a efficient way to match documents within an index.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done (if I understand this correctly).  You would index your terms that/records will be searched on in one pass.  In the second pass, you will search for each term and log results.

Answer (score 0):

While pre-processing the document you can generate a hash that aggregate those fields, and store this (as `NOT_ANALYZED`), this way you just have to search by one field with a known size, take a look at [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html). This is what I normally do for duplicate detection of the file content (since the content might be too big for a single query).

If what you are looking for is creating a more complex query, try using [CachingWrapperFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/CachingWrapperFilter.html), this way subsequent calls to your deduplication algorithm will be much faster.